# How can I load external static Javascript files in ipython or jupyter notebook

Tags: javascript, python, requirejs, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to load d3 and dimple.js in ipython notebook but its throwing error. I have tried require as well but not able to load please provide me some way out of it

Comment: You need node.js kernel to run your notenook.

Answer (score 6):

1. Run this in the notebook to find out your jupyter directory:

   ```
   from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_config_dir
   jupyter_dir = jupyter_config_dir()
   jupyter_dir
   ```
2. Create folder named 'custom' under jupyter directory found from above
      /custom
3. Create custom.js file under  /custom/custom.js and add following

   ```
   requirejs.config({
   paths: {
       d3: 'd3.min',
   }
   });
   ```
4. Open jupyter_notebook_config.py created for your profile. if it is not created ,use the following to create one from the command line/terminal

   ```
   jupyter notebook --generate-config
   ```
5. Modify static path for your js folder in jupyter_notebook_config.py(created from generate-config command) like below

   ```
   c.NotebookApp.extra_static_paths = ["C:\your-js-folder"]
   ```
6. Drop your external js file under C:\your-js-folder and stop and start jupyter notebook